# Handling a Click for all controls on a Form & getting mouse location

Tags: winforms, event-handling, controls, mouseevent

I am working on a windows form that is covered in panels representing a grid.

I'm trying to create an event handler that handles all mouse clicks regardless of which panel the click occurs on and then moves a `PictureBox` to the location of the panel.

I managed to find a topic that covered the event handler, but I am unable to get the location of the mouse click from the event handler. Below is the code I have so far (mostly pinched from another post):

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
    {
        c.MouseClick += new MouseEventHandler(myEvent_handler_click);
    }
}

public void myEvent_handler_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Point point = new Point(e.X, e.Y);

    game.MoveToSquare(point);
}
```

The line of code `Point point = new Point(e.X, e.Y);` doesn't work because I can't refer to the `X` of `e` or the `Y` of `e`.

How can I get the location of the mouse at the time it is clicked?

Any help is appreciated. Feel free to ask me more questions if I wasn't clear enough!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.mouseeventhandler.aspx) for the event handler is defined like so:

```
public delegate void MouseEventHandler(object sender, MouseEventArgs e);
```

[`MouseEventArgs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.mouseeventargs.aspx) inherits from `EventArgs`, that's why your code is working. If you change the definition of your `EventHandler`, you should be able to access the coordinates:

```
public void myEvent_handler_click(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Point point = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
}
```

You can also simply access [`e.Location`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.mouseeventargs.location.aspx) to get point:

```
Point point = e.Location;
```